# LIVE Desktop Alert for Stack Overflow

Tags: app, .net

### About

This app will provide you LIVE desktop notification for new questions posted on StackOverflow. You can add your favorite tags and it will continue searching for new questions. If it finds a new question it will instantly alert you. I created this app with a hope that it will greatly help the experts to get LIVE notification. It took about 15 days to complete this project.

#### License

This is a freeware so you are free to use and redistribute but with proper attribution to us (www.funbutlearn.com)

#### Download

Download Link for the app: [SO-Notifier.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78446200/2013/SO-Notifier.zip). Instruction manual: [How to Use](http://www.funbutlearn.com/2013/03/live-desktop-alert-for-stackoverflowcom.html)

#### Platform

This application only runs on Windows. This has been tested and verified on Windows7 and Windows8.

### Contact

This app has been developed by Hari Shankar Das, a software engineer from India. You can contact him at hdas2012@outlook.com

### Code

This app has been developed with VB.Net. It needs Microsoft .Net Framework to run. To get its source code you have to mail me at hdas2012@outlook.com.

Comment: Why not open source it on GitHub?

Comment: Interesting app, but why the bell icon rather than a nice little Stack Overflow one? Also, it's a shame that the forms are all using the default WinForms icon...